# How to add CP932 charset to iconv in Alpine

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, alpine-linux, iconv

I want to convert CP932 string to UTF-8.

In Ubuntu I can convert string by a command

```
iconv -f CP932 -t UTF-8 [input_file]
```

But the iconv in `Apline 3.17` fails with a error: `iconv: source charset CP932: Invalid argument`.

How can I add CP932 charset to iconv?

The command is called from a ruby script so I don't adhere `iconv` if there is better way to convert string `CP932` to `UTF-8` with ruby or another command line tool in Alpine.

Comment: Perhaps it has a different name. iconv has an option to list the codepages it supports. CP932 is sometimes called Shift-JIS

Comment: CP932(also called Windows-31J) is a variant of Shift-JIS. These are not same.

Comment: Shift-JIS is really a family of encodings. The point is to look for the encoding under an alias in iconv. Another tack is to ask about how to install a codepage or Japanese support in Alpine Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compile `iconv` from source](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) rather than installing it with a package.

1. Install the utilities necessary to build from source:

```bash
apk add --no-cache curl build-base
```

2. Download the source:

```bash
cd /tmp
curl -O https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.17.tar.gz
tar xvf libiconv-1.17.tar.gz
cd libiconv-1.17/
```

3. Configure, compile and install `iconv` to `/usr/local/bin`:

```bash
./configure
make
make install
```

4. Remove the downloaded source:

```bash
cd /tmp
rm -rf libiconv-1.17/
rm libiconv-1.17.tar.gz
```

---

Now you can run `iconv` successfully with CP932. Here's an example:

1. Create a new UTF-8 file:

```bash
echo "潤" > foo
```

2. Confirm it is UTF-8:

```bash
file -i foo
foo: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

3. Convert it to CP932:

```bash
iconv -f UTF-8 -t CP932 foo > foo.cp932
```

4. Confirm it has been converted:

```bash
file -i foo.cp932
foo.cp932: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit
```

and:

```bash
cat foo.cp932
��
```

5. Convert CP932 back to UTF-8:

```bash
iconv -f CP932 -t UTF-8 foo.cp932 > foo.utf8
```

6. Confirm it has been properly converted:

```bash
file -i foo.utf8
foo.utf8: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

and:

```bash
cat foo.utf8
潤
```

and:

```bash
md5sum foo
54282143d705814d6ba671b783f2e0ba  foo

md5sum foo.utf8
54282143d705814d6ba671b783f2e0ba  foo.utf8
```